# Firefox Keeps Crashing Over and Over

Tags: 10.10, firefox

Here is what Firefox says when it crashes:

```
Add-ons: {e968fc70-8f95-4ab9-9e79-304de2a71ee1}:0.7.3,langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org:11.0,langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org:11.0,ubufox@ubuntu.com:0.9.4,{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:11.0,jid0-qvNTOHrOc01SzSinPbesRVcpAoY@jetpack:1.1.1,jid0-YxzrUsJ0WOiOaU89TngAzLcIs18@jetpack:0.7.5
BuildID: 20120310193444
CrashTime: 1335509696
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 00000000f0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1335270972
Notes: OpenGL: DRI R300 Project -- Mesa DRI R300 (RS400 5A62) 20090101 x86/MMX/SSE2 NO-TCL DRI2 -- 1.5 Mesa 7.9-devel -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 325
StartupTime: 1335509380
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 11.0

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

It doesn't crash every time I start it just most of the time, sometimes it will run fine until it crashes then I start it up and it crashes repeatedly, then it will stay normal and run fine after a few restarts and then start again.

Comment: Does it run properly in safe mode? You can put it in safe mode with `firefox -safe-mode`
If it does, then it probably means that an addon or plugin is causing issues

Comment: It seems to be running fine in safe mode, but then again sometimes it runs fine normally as well.. I have no idea which addon it could be because it did this before I installed any of my custom addons.. the only one I could assume it is is the Ubuntu Firefox Modifications 0.9.4

Comment: The other thing that comes to mind to me is that it could be the flash plugin (or any of the other default plugins) playing up. The only thing I can thing of doing is disabling all your custom addons, then disabling the plugins and ubuntu addon one by one until the problem stops occurring (that is if it stops occurring)

Comment: It now returns in Firefox 29 running in Ubuntu 12.04... perhaps my graphics card became too old?

Answer (score 1):

### Gathering Information About Your Firefox Installation

Since this is a bug, you should consider submitting the crash report. It sounds from your question like you're getting a crash report to submit data to Mozilla.org, rather than to Launchpad. That suggests that you're not running the version of Firefox that comes with Ubuntu. If the following advice doesn't solve your problem, you should edit your question to provide the output of the following commands in the Terminal:

```
apt-cache policy firefox
firefox -v
which -a firefox
```

### A Simple Fix That Often Works

However, you may simply be able to solve this problem by clearing out your Firefox profile. To do this, make sure Firefox is not running. Then, *if you do not use other Mozilla applications such as Thunderbird*, run this command:

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.old
```

Alternatively, *if you do use other Mozilla applications such as Thunderbird*, run this command:

```
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox ~/.mozilla/firefox.old
```

Then run Firefox and see if the problem is fixed. You won't have your bookmarks, cache, cookies, saved passwords, and other data, but it's likely that Firefox will be repaired.

This technique doesn't actually delete your user-specific Firefox data; instead, it moves it out of the way so Firefox doesn't use it.

To restore it--which would break Firefox again, if this fixed it--first make sure Firefox is not running. Then do this if you followed the first method:

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.new
mv ~/.mozilla.old ~/.mozilla
```

Or this if you followed the second method:

```
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox ~/.mozilla/firefox.new
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox.old ~/.mozilla/firefox
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want you can install Chromium for web browsing. Just open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you'll be asked for your password. As you type it, it won't appear on the screen, but that's fine. Then press enter. If you're then asked if you really want to install, press <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Before installing software in the Terminal with `sudo apt-get install ...`, it's advisable to run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Installing chromium is a workaround and less a solution to make Firefox work again.